# controlling vibration frequency and amplitude of a motor

Tags: actuator, vibration

I want to build a hardware circuit that can control the frequency and amplitude of motors. I have a few questions about this.

1) What kind of actuator do I need to use?
I have used ERM motors and the frequency and the amplitude changes together with different voltages. What kind of actuators and drivers do I need to use to control the frequency and amplitude (varying frequency with the constant amplitude or varying the amplitude with the constant frequency).

2) How can I control the actuator?
I looked into some datasheets about LRA and tactors, but I couldn't find how to control their vibrations. Please leave a link or some comments about how to use the actuator in the question 1. (Using Arduino or other microcontrollers).

3) I have used other ERM motors for other project (e.g. the motor in this link. http://www.adafruit.com/product/1201). Is there any actuator that I can control the frequency and amplitude as described in question 1 with the small size like the motor in the link?

Answer (score 1):

The ERM motor vibrates because of an unbalanced mass attached to its rotor.

The frequency of the vibrations is directly proportional to the motor's RPM. While the RPM depends on the voltage applied to the motor.

The "amplitude" of the vibration as you call it is a function of the frequency hence the drive voltage. Therefore you can't control the frequency and the "amplitude" separately.

Comment: Can I control the frequency and amplitude separately with different actuators? If it is possible, what type of actuator do I need to use?

Comment: It depends on your application. If you want to stick to motors you could mount a small servo on the shaft of a much larger motor. The servo would change the center of gravity of the rotating mass hence changing the 'amplitude' of the vibration while changing the RPM of the larger motor would change the frequency.